# Getting the location of a mouse click event from a JButton

Tags: java, jbutton, mouselistener

I've got something like this:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {    
    ((JButton)a.getSource()).setBackground(Color.red);              
}
```

The color changes successfully, but I need to change a value in a `int` array according to the clicked button. How can I get the X and Y coordinates of the location where the mouse is clicked in a JButton array?

Comment: Use some kind of `Map` instead or use an [`Action`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) which provides a single unit of work which can applied to buttons, menu items and key bindings

Comment: won;t the simple getX() and getY() functions work?

Comment: @user2837260: that will get the x and y location of the pressed JButton component, not the row and column index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way: use a 2D array of JButton and iterate through the array via nested for loops to get the row and column value. For example...

```
int r = -1;
int c = -1;
for (int row = 0; row < buttons.length; row++) {
  for (int col = 0; col < buttons[row].length; col++) {
    if (buttons[row][col] == e.getSource()) {
      r = row;
      c = col;
    }
  }
}
```

Edit: other options (as mentioned by MadProgrammer), use a Map to map your JButton or its Action, to a Color.